# Not loading model in three Js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

Im doing my project with Python(Django) and three.js, I've got the following code. It should animate pyramid and when the real model is loaded change the pyramid by it. But when object is loaded I just see a spinable white cube and error message 'HREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D'. Please help, and advice how to fix it.

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Three.js Basic Scene with Controls and Model Loading</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.139.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
        let scene, camera, renderer, controls, objectToRotate;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            // Scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // Camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 5;

            // Renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            // OrbitControls
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            // Pyramid
            const pyramidGeometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry(1, 1.5, 4);
            const pyramidMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x808080 });
            const pyramid = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidGeometry, pyramidMaterial);
            scene.add(pyramid);
            objectToRotate = pyramid;

            //Light
            const ambient = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(0xffffff, 1);
            scene.add(ambient)

            let light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,1);
            light.position.set(0, 300, 500);
            scene.add(light)

            let light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,1);
            light2.position.set(500, 300, 500);
            scene.add(light2)

            // Resize
            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

            // Mouse events
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

            // Load GLTF Model
            const gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            gltfLoader.load(
                '{% static "img/scene.gltf" %}',
                function (gltf) {
                    scene.remove(objectToRotate);
                    objectToRotate = gltf.scene;
                    scene.add(objectToRotate);
                },
                function (xhr) {
                    console.log('GLTF model ' + (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.error('Error loading GLTF model:', error);
                }
            );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }

        function onMouseDown(event) {
            controls.enabled = false;
        }

        function onMouseMove(event) {
            // Rotate
            if (controls.enabled === false) {
                const deltaX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
                const deltaY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;
                objectToRotate.rotation.y -= deltaX * 0.01;
                objectToRotate.rotation.x -= deltaY * 0.01;
            }
        }

        function onMouseUp(event) {
            controls.enabled = true;
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Debug your code in your browser's dev tools. Place a breakpoint on this line: `scene.remove(objectToRotate);`. When the breakpoint stops the code execution, inspect the `gltf` variable, specifically `gltf.scene` to enure it is a proper type that can be added to your scene.